# USB not found in GParted

Tags: usb, gparted

My Ubuntu 16.04 is unable to recognize and format a usb drive. Below are things I tried:

- When I try opening disks, it does show a "Generic USB Flash Disk" as `/dev/sdb`, but all options (including Format Partition), except for Edit Mount Options, are grayed out.
- GParted does not recognize the device (`/dev/sdb`) at all.
- `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb` returns `No medium found`

Any idea?

Comment: try to see it by fdisk command

Comment: Try zeroing it out first with `dd`.

Comment: Is it mounted? `gparted` will not alter mounted devices. Try `sudo umount /dev/sdb` first.

Comment: @Sinoosh fdisk does not see the USB

Comment: @AndroidDev I think you mean `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb`? Got the error `dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': No medium found`

Comment: @waltinator I got `umount: /dev/sdb: not mounted`

Comment: After inserting the USB drive, you might open a terminal, enter the **dmesg** command and scan the tail end of the output to see if dmesg reports anything unusual.

Comment: What's the output of `lsusb` and `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/usb*`?

Comment: Unplug the pendrive, reboot the computer, plug in the pendrive. Try again to wipe it (actually it is enough to wipe the first megabyte). Try in other USB ports of the computer. Try in at least one other computer. If still no luck, I am afraid that the pendrive is damaged beyond repair. See this link about pendrive lifetime, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297

Comment: That was an old usb stick so I forgot about it sometime ago. I would not be able to respond to any comment. Sorry everyone

Answer (score -1):

there is a  little menu up to the top right of the Gparted dialog box click it and see if you can switch to the  flash drive. It's how I do it